# How to separate silence from frequencies in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, segmentation

For a project, I was asked to create a DTMF detector on Matlab. I know that the audio sample that will be provided will have 4 tones maximum, possibly less, and that the audio begins with a 0.1 second silence. Each of the tones lasts 0.5-2 seconds, and a silence of 0.1-1.5 seconds follows it. I do not for sure what the length of the file will be, as it may contain anything from 1-4 tones.

I understood that I first need to separate each tone in order to run it through a bank of band pass filters and determine its two original frequencies. This needs to be done by measuring the power/energy of the signal at various points. I looked at the documentation and found findchangepts(). Am I on the right path?

Comment: what documentation?

Comment: Matlab documentation! I forgot to mention that I was using it.

Comment: i don’t think you need to separate the tones prior to filtering. DTMF modems didn’t do that

Comment: even with multiple tones? I fail to see how I can pass the entire signal through and hope my function picks up all the tones.

Comment: for a modem, you use a bank of filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of the problem, you don't need to separate tones before passing to the bandpass filters(assuming that bandpass filters allows only DTMF tones to pass through).

Pass the audio samples through DTMF bandpass filter, if any DTMF tones are present the filtered output will have non zero energy/power, if the tones are not present the energy/power of filtered audio will be close to zero. this criteria can be used to detect silence.